# Computing a limit involving exponential functiom

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Consider some sequences $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}, \{c_n\}$. Suppose
$$
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n)=0\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}c_n=d
\end{cases}
$$
for some $d\in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to show that
$$
\exp(a_n)c_n=\exp(-b_n)d+o(1)
$$

---

What I want to show is equivalent to showing that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [\exp(a_n)c_n-\exp(-b_n)d]=0
$$
I don't know how to proceed from here. Any hint would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: $a_n = n$, $b_n  = -n$, $c_n = 1/n$, $d=0$ looks like a counter-example.

Comment: Did you forget to mention anything about the convergence of $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: It would suffice to require that $a_n$ is *bounded.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MartinR points out, the statement is not true for $a_n, b_n, c_n \in \mathbb R$. A counterexample is $c_n=\frac 1n$, $a_n = n$, $b_n = -n$.

The statement *is* true, however, if we assume $a_n, b_n \ge 0$. In which case we know that both $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$$ $$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$$

Therefore the last limit is easy to compute, as all limits exists:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [\exp(a_n)c_n-\exp(-b_n)d]= $$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp(a_n) \cdot \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_n - d\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp(-b_n) = 1 \cdot d - d \cdot 1 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not even true for constant $c_n = 1$. With $a_n = n$,
$b_n = \frac 1n - n$ we have
$$
 \exp(a_n) - \exp(-b_n) = \exp(n) - \exp(n - \frac 1n)
 = \exp(n) \bigl(1 - \exp(-\frac 1n) \bigr) \to \infty
$$
since $1 - \exp(-\frac 1n) \sim \frac 1n$ for $n \to  \infty$.

However, it becomes true if $(a_n)$ – or equivalently, $(b_n)$ – is assumed to be a *bounded* sequence:
$$
\exp(a_n) c_n - \exp(-b_n) d = \bigl(1 - \exp(-a_n - b_n) \bigr)
 \exp(a_n) c_n + (c_n - d) \exp(-b_n) \\ \to 0
$$
because $$1 - \exp(-a_n - b_n) \to 0 \\ c_n - d \to 0$$
and all other factors are bounded.